# How to send List<ArraySegment<byte>> in SslStream

Tags: c#, sockets, sslstream

I want to send List> through SslStream. We can send this using Socke.Send but i want SSL security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (var segment in segments)
{
    sslStream.Write(segment.Array, segment.Offset, segment.Count);
}
```